# How can I set the expire time in Redis' ruby client when using mapped_mset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am trying to use

```
redis.mapped_mset({ "f1" => "v1", "f2" => "v2" })
```

to set multiple keys into `Redis` and I can not set expire time at the same time.
The only way to set expire time to to use this:

```
set(key, value, options = {})
```

or

```
expire(key, seconds)
```

I have to call many times and this is not what I want to see.
Are there any other ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis itself [does not support](https://redis.io/commands) multiple setting with an expiration parameter. [`Redis#mapped_set`](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L822) is a syntactic sugar to call `mset` and `mset` itself is a syntactic sugar to transactionally call subsequent `set` many times.

So, the only thing you need is to wrap subsequent calls to `set(... ex:...)` into a transaction with `Redis#multi`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: But I don't care whether these set operation are in same transaction, does this mean I can call them separately without using Redis#multi?

Comment: You have asked for an equivalent of `mapped_mset` with expiration. `mapped_mset` is a transacted atomic operation. If you don’t want it to be atomic, call it without `multi`.

Comment: I totally understand what you mean. One more thing I want to confirm, if a hash parameter contains N keys,  redis client will send N `set` requests to server, right?

Comment: I have linked both sources of where to get answers. No, since Redis supports `mset` command, ruby wrapper will send 1 `MSET` request to Redis, which Redis will internally execute as a transacted set.

Answer (score 4):

You can write wrapper method to set a list and add expiration. Use `redis.multi` to wrap it into trasactional module.

```
def set_list(list, expire_in = 10)
  redis.multi do
    list.each{ |k, v| redis.set(k,v, ex: expire_in)}
  end
end
```